How do you take logcats with Appium?
Im working on automating testing an Android app with Appium 2.5.1 using Python Appium Client and Pytest. It would be nice to be able to take logcat for each test separately and save it to a file. I found that I can get logcat using WebDriver:
logcat = self.driver.get_log('logcat')


but unsure what would be the best way to dump it to a file so it is in nice and readable form.
Anyone?
So far I tried using python logger but I think this might not be the best solution so wonder how other people do this? I am already using python logger for my other framework messages.
